# Enlarging vectors ($V_1$ and $V_2$) to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The solution to the answer is what I am trying to understand.
I have two vectors denoted by $V_{1}=(1,-2,3)$ and $V_{2}=(0,5,-3)$
The question states to enlarge ($V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$) to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

the solution says $V_{3}=(a,b,c)$ with $9a-3b-5c$.

I put the vectors in a column of a matrix then I augmented it by a $3 \times3$ identity matrix.The reduced echelon form that I got is
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0 & 0& \frac13 & \frac59  \\
0&1&0 & \frac13 & \frac29 \\
0&0&1 & -\frac13 & -\frac59
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I understand that the first two columns correspond to the first two vectors so then the third column is the missing vector $V_{3}=(0,0,1)$. The solution however is different and I am wondering what procedures I am missing so I can derive the given solution.

Comment: To be clear... Does the question ask you to find **any** basis for $\Bbb R^3$?  If so, your answer, as well as uncountably infinitely many other answers including the given solution, is fine and correct.  If it were asking you to find a third vector which is orthogonal to both of the first two however, then that is a different question.

Comment: As for what process would have yielded an answer of $(9,-3,-5)$, that would be the cross product of your two given vectors.

Comment: i cross multiplied, and found the determinate to be -9a+3b+5c so (-9,3,5). is that still the equivalent as the textbook answer (9,-3,-5)? @JMoravitz

Comment: Obviously, it is just the third vector in the other direction than the textbook answer and also one of the infinitely many correct answers.  Had you changed the order in which you cross multiplied you would have gotten that instead.